# Use of @select in a Play! Framework 2.3 template and Java

Tags: java, scala, playframework-2.0

I am trying to use a 'select' form element in Play! 2.3, and cannot get it to work. What do I supply to the template? Currently I have this:

```
public static Result add(Long sensorId) {
    Form<Action> myForm = Form.form(Action.class);

    Sensor sensor = Sensor.find.byId(sensorId);
    Action action = new Action();
    action.actionUp = true;
    action.sensor = sensor;
    myForm.fill(action);

    HashMap<String, String> devices = new HashMap<>();
    for(Device device : Device.find.all()){
        devices.put(device.id.toString(), device.name);
    }

    return ok(editView.render(myForm, action, devices));
}
```

And the template:

```
@(myForm: Form[models.Action], action: models.Action, deviceList: HashMap[String, String])

@helper.select(myForm("device"), deviceList,'_label -> "Perform on device")
```

But that doesn't work as it expects a Seq[(String, String)].
I cannot find a way to create that in Java though... any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form helper won't know, if you directly place the `deviceList` in `select` and in the end, it expects `options` from you. That is the reason, it shows this error `expects a Seq[(String, String)]`.

To solve this you must wrap the `deviceList` by `options` to let helper know `deviceList` is the `options` for `select`.

So it should be like following.

```
@helper.select(myForm("device"), options(deviceList),'_label -> "Perform on device")
```

Comment: Ok, I saw the 'options()' possibility mentioned, but for me it has to be @helper.options(); Now it works.